# How to get numbers of available seats Galileo UAPI Air

Tags: web-services, galileo, travelport-api

How can I get numbers of seats available for particular journey/segment in LowFareSearchRes air Galileo.

I am sending the [LowFareSearchReq](https://support.travelport.com/webhelp/uapi/uAPI.htm#Air/Low_Fare_Shopping/Low_Fare_Shopping_(Synchronous).htm%3FTocPath%3DAir%7CAir%2520Shopping%2520and%2520Booking%7CLow%2520Fare%2520Shopping%7C_____2) request as below to Galileo For flight availability,I am using Travelport UAPI.

```
<s:Envelope
    xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
        <Action s:mustUnderstand="1"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">localhost:8080/kestrel/AirService
        </Action>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema-instance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema">
        <LowFareSearchReq SolutionResult="true" AuthorizedBy="user" TraceId="0cd5900e3ba1b7143227a16dab585443" TargetBranch="********"
            xmlns="http://www.travelport.com/schema/air_v39_0">
            <BillingPointOfSaleInfo OriginApplication="UAPI"
                xmlns="http://www.travelport.com/schema/common_v39_0" />
                <SearchAirLeg>
                    <SearchOrigin>
                        <CityOrAirport Code="DXB"
                            xmlns="http://www.travelport.com/schema/common_v39_0" />
                        </SearchOrigin>
                        <SearchDestination>
                            <CityOrAirport Code="MNL"
                                xmlns="http://www.travelport.com/schema/common_v39_0" />
                            </SearchDestination>
                            <SearchDepTime PreferredTime="2017-12-22" />
                            <AirLegModifiers>
                                <PreferredCabins>
                                    <CabinClass Type="Business"
                                        xmlns="http://www.travelport.com/schema/common_v39_0">
                                    </CabinClass>
                                </PreferredCabins>
                            </AirLegModifiers>
                        </SearchAirLeg>
                        <SearchAirLeg>
                            <SearchOrigin>
                                <CityOrAirport Code="MNL"
                                    xmlns="http://www.travelport.com/schema/common_v39_0" />
                                </SearchOrigin>
                                <SearchDestination>
                                    <CityOrAirport Code="DXB"
                                        xmlns="http://www.travelport.com/schema/common_v39_0" />
                                    </SearchDestination>
                                    <SearchDepTime PreferredTime="2017-12-30" />
                                    <AirLegModifiers>
                                        <PreferredCabins>
                                            <CabinClass Type="Business"
                                                xmlns="http://www.travelport.com/schema/common_v39_0">
                                            </CabinClass>
                                        </PreferredCabins>
                                    </AirLegModifiers>
                                </SearchAirLeg>
                                <AirSearchModifiers MaxSolutions="100"></AirSearchModifiers>
                                <SearchPassenger Code="ADT"
                                    xmlns="http://www.travelport.com/schema/common_v39_0" />
                                    <AirPricingModifiers FaresIndicator="AllFares">
                                        <AccountCodes>
                                            <AccountCode Code="*****"
                                                xmlns="http://www.travelport.com/schema/common_v39_0"/>
                                            </AccountCodes>
                                        </AirPricingModifiers>
                                    </LowFareSearchReq>
                                </s:Body>
                            </s:Envelope>
```

find the response for the above request [here](https://pastebin.com/G9rvQiyp)

I am trying to get the number of seats available for the particular journey/Segment in the response.

I am not too sure for getting the number of seats available in the response please let me know how should I send the request with proper details.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share some code please ? Show us what you are trying to achieve precisely

Comment: @DarkMukke,please check my edit in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so after reading up various sites, I finally found out. Here is how to do this.

We can use the `SeatMapReq/Rsp` to get the number of available seats in a given flight.

Check the example [here](https://support.travelport.com/webhelp/uapi/uAPI.htm#Seat%20Maps/Seat_Maps.htm%3FTocPath%3DAir%7CSeat%2520Maps%7C_____0).

Update:- Even in the response of LFS, we can get in BookingCount attribute of air:BookingInfo.